# LDA with three variabilities

Tags: data-transformation, descriptive-statistics, discriminant-analysis

In a classical linear discriminant analysis (LDA), we usually have only two variabilities to handle (the between classes and the between individual variability). Usually LDA is used to maxmize the first and minimize the second.

But what if I have three variabilities to work with ? 
I have a set of classes, in each class there is a set of individuals (vectors) and for each individual I can generate a set of vectors (multiple views of the same individual under different conditions).

So in the end, I want to maximize the variability between the different classes, minimize the variability between vectors corresponding to the same class, minimize the variability of vectors (or views) corresponding to the same individual.

Is there a LDA variant or any other way to do this ? 
Thanks folks !

Comment: How do your data look like, what the variables?

Comment: Intuitively, I don't think this is possible. I'm thinking of an overdetermined system of equations.

Comment: Why don't you consider all the points inside each class (multiple views of multiple individuals) as contributing to the same within-class variance? What do you gain by separating these two, if you want to maximize class separability with respect to both? I think this trivially reduces to standard LDA, at least as it is formulated now.

Comment: thanks for all your answers, I finally went with LDA by supposing that all views of all individuals come form the same class.